# Calculated 'Across' Variable in PROC REPORT

Tags: sas

I'm trying to use a alias to create multiple statistics for the same variable in PROC REPORT. This is an elaboration on a previous post I put up, but am posting it as a separate question because the sample data has changed and the question is a bit more involved.

```
data have1;
   input username $  betdate : datetime. stake winnings winner;
   dateOnly = datepart(betdate) ;
   format betdate DATETIME.;
   format dateOnly ddmmyy8.;
   datalines; 
    player1 12NOV2008:12:04:01 90 -90 0
    player1 04NOV2008:09:03:44 100 40 1
    player2 07NOV2008:14:03:33 120 -120 0
    player1 05NOV2008:09:00:00 50 15 1
    player1 05NOV2008:09:05:00 30 5 1
    player1 05NOV2008:09:00:05 20 10 1
    player2 09NOV2008:10:05:10 10 -10 0
    player2 09NOV2008:10:05:40 15 -15 0
    player2 09NOV2008:10:05:45 15 -15 0
    player2 09NOV2008:10:05:45 15 45 1
    player2 15NOV2008:15:05:33 35 -35 0
    player1 15NOV2008:15:05:33 35 15 1
    player1 15NOV2008:15:05:33 35 15 1
run;

PROC PRINT; RUN;

Proc rank data=have1 ties=mean out=ranksout1 groups=2;
     var    stake winner;
     ranks  stakeRank winnerRank;
run;

PROC TABULATE DATA=ranksout1 NOSEPS;
    VAR stake;
    class stakerank winnerrank;
    TABLE stakerank = '', winnerrank=''*stake=''*(N Mean Skewness);
RUN;
```

The output provided by tabulate above is what I want, although I will ultimately be adding some more calculated fields so would like to do this with PROC REPORT.

```
PROC REPORT DATA=ranksout1 NOWINDOWS;
    COLUMN stakerank winnerrank, (N stake=stakemean discountedstake);
    DEFINE stakerank / GROUP '' ORDER=INTERNAL;
    DEFINE winnerrank / ACROSS '' ORDER=INTERNAL;
    DEFINE stake / ANALYSIS N 'Count';
    DEFINE stakemean / ANALYSIS MEAN 'Mean' format=8.2;
    DEFINE discountedstake / computed format=8.2;
    COMPUTE discountedstake;
        discountedstake = stakemean * 0.9;
    ENDCOMP;
RUN;
```

When I start grouping the variables 'ACROSS' using commas and brackets, I can't seem to insert a calculated variable at all. It works if I only GROUP once on stakerank, but if I introduce the winnerrank grouping, it doesn't work. I get errors telling me that 'missing values were generated', and that 'stakemean is uninitialized'.

Would appreciate any tips at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps:
preparing calculated variable in SAS view on detail data:

```
data ranks_view / view=ranks_view;
set ranksout1;
    discountedstake = stake * 0.9;
run;

PROC REPORT DATA=ranks_view NOWINDOWS;
    COLUMN stakerank winnerrank, (N stake=stakemean discountedstake);
    DEFINE stakerank / GROUP '' ORDER=INTERNAL;
    DEFINE winnerrank / ACROSS '' ORDER=INTERNAL;
    DEFINE stake / ANALYSIS N 'Count';
    DEFINE stakemean / ANALYSIS MEAN 'Mean' format=8.2;
    DEFINE discountedstake / ANALYSIS MEAN format=8.2;
RUN;
```

In `DEFINE discountedstake / ANALYSIS MEAN format=8.2;` - MEAN says the result is average of discountedstake.

Comment: Great. I'm still intrigued by the computed variables though. Is it possible to have a computed variable iterate at the row level in the input dataset and then report at the group level. For example, a computed variable that calculates the sum of squares for the variable i.e. sum((stake-stakemean^2)). Would this be possible if stake was included, but not displayed, so that the calculation would run on each row, but that the data would then be grouped to display it? I need to include the skewness for each group, so I need to get as far as that with a computed variable, I think.

Comment: I'd use PROC UNIVARIATE to calculate skewness.

Comment: Ok, will try to do that for skewness. Is there a restriction on adding a computed variable to an ACROSS group or something? Can you only put in N, Mean, Sum etc?

Comment: It is possible to use arrays in computed variables, and to iterate through them at the row level.  You could then use a calculated variable to calculate your (whatever) and report it at the group level, using COMPUTE AFTER.

Comment: Couldn't work out how to calculate at the row level and then aggregate at the group level, but found a (horrible) workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766635/calculate-skewness-in-proc-report/18794285#18794285